# Accidentally opened back of analogue camera while rewinding film, are all pictures lost?

Tags: film, exposure, yashica

I shot an entire roll of film on a Yashica FX-3 Super. While I was rewinding the film to remove, I thought I had rewound it all and opened the back. However, the film was not completely rewound and so some of it was exposed. How many pictures will be lost? Will the film that was already rewound be ok?

Answer (score 2):

Why *wouldn't* the film that was already rewound be ok? The film inside the cassette is protected from light, don't you agree?

How much film remained outside the cassette? That's the film that was entirely flooded with light. Consider that each frame is 36mm in width, along with a gap between frames of approx 2mm. Also consider the "leader" portion at the start of the roll, where there are no pictures to begin with.

Comment: It is possible that only the leader remained exposed, as it was almost fully rewound at the time

Answer (score 1):

Anything that wasn't safely back in the film canister may be lost, certainly anything directly in the camera back & not wound onto either spool.

You'll find out precisely when you get the roll developed - usually they don't charge for completely ruined shots.

Answer (score 0):

For some workflows rewinding just enough to leave a leader outside the film can is actually desirable. It makes it possible to wind bulk film onto commercial metal film cans since you didn't have to use the can opener on it for example.
If the amount left out is small enough to not be wound on the takeup mechanism, or just barely wound, then you might have figured out the feeling of doing it on this camera.